# Condition for a sum of images of fundamental dominant weights to lie on a wall

Tags: root-systems, weyl-group

Let $\Delta$ be a system of simple roots in a root system with Weyl group $W$. For $\alpha\in\Delta$, let $\varpi_\alpha$ be the corresponding fundamental dominant weight. Let $w\neq r$ be elements of $W$. I would like to show that
$$
w\left(\sum_{\substack{\alpha\in\Delta \\ w(\alpha)<0}}\varpi_\alpha\right)+ r\left(\sum_{\substack{\beta\in\Delta \\ r(\beta)>0}}\varpi_\beta\right)
$$
always lies on a wall.

I can show this in type $A$, but only by choosing bases and doing some casework computations.

In general, it is easy to check that this is true when:

- $w$ is the identity
- $w$ and $r$ differ by a single simple reflection
- $w$ and $r$ are distinct simple reflections
- $w=w_0$ and $r$ is a simple reflection or $\ell(r)=2$.

Comment: I think that you can reduce to the case $w = 1$ by replacing $r$ by $w^{-1}r w$ and $\Delta$ by $w^{-1}\Delta$.

Comment: @LSpice, But if $w=r$ and is not the identity, then the above expression doesn't lie on a wall, but the corresponding expression with respect to $w^{-1}\Delta$ for $w'=1$ and $r'=w^{-1}rw=r=w$ does. It is late though, so I am likely just confused.

Comment: Why does it lie on a wall when $w = 1$?  I am too lazy to check in general, but, for $W = \mathsf A_1$ and $r$ the non-identity element, I get that the sum is $\rho$ (or $\delta$, or whatever you call the half-sum of positive roots).

Comment: If $w=1$ then the first sum is empty, and the 2nd sum is a sum of some fundamental weights, but not all.